# Theorem 1.13 (a) Rudin functional analysis. $V$ is one?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

> Let $X$ a topological vector space. If $A \subset X$ then $\bar{A}
> = \bigcap (A + V)$, where $V$ runs through all the neighborhoods of $0$.

The proof seems ok until the very last bit.

Basically if $x \in \bar{A}$ then $(x + V) \cap A \neq \emptyset$, for any $V$ neighborhood of $0$, this happens if and only if $x \in A - V$ for every such $V$. After I don't get the meaning of the following

> Since $-V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ if and only if $V$ is one, the
>   proof is complete.

What's the meaning of "$V$ is one"?

Comment: What does "=>" mean here?

Comment: @DonAntonio it was clearly a typo...

Comment: Well, it is clear it was *now*...

Comment: $-V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ if and only if $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Here "if $V$ is one" means "if $V$ is also a neighborhood of $0$". So $-V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ if and only if $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ as well (since $0=-0$).

Comment: I can't believe I was this stupid... I thought he meant some property with some terminology.

Comment: It's not stupid, it's just being very careful. Lots of times in math something "is one" has a specific meaning (eg ring theory).

Comment: Say this out loud:  "1 is an integer if and only if 0 is one."...+1, especially for your follow-up comment.